# Условие, результат которого - false, возвращает ошибку. Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, if, условия

Есть список: `input_ = ['2', '+', '6', '/','4']`.

Есть условие:

```
if '*' in input_ and '/' not in input_ or input_.index('/') > input_.index('*'):
```

Компилятор выкидывает ошибку:

> if '*' in input_ and '/' not in input_ or input_.index('/') > input_.index('*'):
>
> ValueError: '*' is not in list

Это как вообще работает?) А что дальше?

```
if 2 == 3:
    pass
```

**ОШИБКА, 2 не равно 3!** Так что ли?)

UPD:

Вот весь код:

```
def calc(input_):
    print(input_)
    if type( input_ ) == type( '' ) : 
        input_ = input_.split(' ')
    if '*' in input_ and '/' not in input_ or input_.index('/') > input_.index('*'):
        sim = input_.index('*')
        left = int ( input_.pop(sim - 1) )
        right = int ( input_.pop(sim) )
        input_[ input_.index('*') ] = left * right
        print(input_)
        calc(input_)
    elif '/' in input_:
        sim = input_.index('/')
        left = int ( input_.pop(sim - 1) )
        right = int ( input_.pop(sim) )
        input_[ input_.index('/') ] = left / right
        print(input_)
        calc(input_) 
    elif ('+' in input_) and ('*' not in input_ and '/' not in input_):
        print (input_)
        print ('+ interation')

calc('2 + 2 * 3 / 4')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Понял, компилятор ругается конкретно эту часть условия: `or input_.index('/') > input_.index('*'):` Так как `'*'` нет в списке, получается ошибка из-за `input_index('*')`. Остаётся только вкладывать условие в условие.

Comment: Правильно. Вот только не компиялтор, а интерпретатор. Используйте `'*' in _index` чтобы убедиться что элемент есть в списке, тогда `input_.index('*')` будет безопасным -- не выбросит исключение и вернет индекс элемента

Comment: @gil9red второй раз? Вот так? `if '*' in input_ and '/' not in input_ or ( '*' in input_ and input_.index('/') > input_.index('*')):`  Работает, но выглядит очень плохо)

Comment: Например так, но мне непонятно условие (да и лениво его разбирать), поэтому не лезу советами по коду :)

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы не путаться в цепочке сложных условий, индексы можно вычислить заранее

```
if len(input_) == 1:
    return
# прибавляем единицу, для совмещения свойств логической и позиционной переменной
operation_idx = lambda char: char in input_ and input_.index(char) + 1
multiply_idx = operation_idx('*')
divide_idx  = operation_idx('/')
if multiply_idx or divide_idx:
    if multiply_idx < divide_idx:   # умножаем
    else:                           # делим
else:
    add_idx = operation_idx('+')
    subtrac_idx  = operation_idx('-')
    if add_idx < subtrac_idx:       # сложение
    else:                           # вычитание
```